# php MVC and GD library

Tags: php, model-view-controller, gd

I have a php project with an MVC structure. The MVC structure is a basic one, with 3 folders (model, view and controller).

In my application I need to create some images from the GD library.
In which part of my MVC structure should I put the GD code?

Comment: Just because you have three things it does not mean you are using MVC. As for where GD code should be: probably somewhere in the domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be in the *controller*:

**Model** is where your data and datastructures live.

**View** is where your interface lives. This is what the user is going to see.

**Controller** is where the "business logic" lives. Here you do what is necessary to get data from your views into your models and vice versa.

Note that this is a very high level overview, but in my experience it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the feedback. Can you explain why it was wrong instead of voting me down without any discussion or arguments? I know some people are of the opinion that business logic should go into the model, but that doesn't make my answer "completely wrong". I mean, people like Jeff Atwoord share my point of view: https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/

Comment: Model layer is where business logic lives. It is a layer (singular) and there are no "models". Controllers are responsible tor altering model layers state. You kinda got what "views" are correct, but since you are one of "artisans", I probably should point out that view is not a template and templates are not supposed to be rendered by controllers.

Comment: And I wonder, how did you come to the conclusion, that what Jeff wrote is any way similar to your description. Then again, I guess I am just a newbie at this mvc-thing and should shut up.

Comment: Yeah, so it's just a matter of opinion. I know about the view, hence the *Note that this is a very high level overview, but in my experience it's a good rule of thumb.*.  This discussion probably means the question is bad though, so maybe we should close it. Thanks for the heads up on what the model layer does by the way, seems like I didn't necessarily understand what Jeff said.